# Ошибки JQ. change not a function

Tags: jquery

Столкнулся с  такой проблемой.

Пишу свою функцию , передаю в нее переменную `element`. Переменная `element` содержит в себе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Начинаю с ней работать.

```
element.change(function () {

});
```

И вылетает ошибка:

> ```
> element.change is not a function
> ```

А если  написать вот так , все начинает работать

```
$('select.filter-select').change(function () {

});
```

Почему ему не нравится `element` и он не хочет работать с ним? В чем соль?

Comment: Код по передачи элемента будет?

Comment: Приходит вот от сюда  onchange="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["FILTER_NAME"]."_".$arItem["ID"])?>')"

Answer (score 0):

Потому что функция `change` доступна только для объектов jQuery.

Попробуйте так:

```
$(element).change(function () {

});
```